# C++ comparing a character of a string

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors, char

Ok, so input is a string. When I try to compile the following code I get

```
c.cpp:42:10: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
```

Why?

```
if(input[i] != ' ')
{   
    char s = input[i];
    if(s == "+")
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `"+"` is a character *string*. Use `'+'` instead.

Comment: Please show ALL relevant code, such as "input" declaration, etc.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I think Roddy got it and Vlad answered ...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you didn't read your book yet.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: Irrelevant. Questions form part of the SO Q&A database. Doesn't matter if someone guessed what the question meant. We expect questions to be sensical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use single quotes in this statement

```
if(s == "+")
```

as here

```
if(s == '+')
```

Comment: Better to explain _why_. This answer solves the OP's compiler error but leaves him absolutely clueless as to what his code change means. Not a good way to teach.

Answer (score 2):

As char `s` is a character so it can only be compared against another character or ascii value.
Double quotes (`" "`) are used for string while single quotes (`' '`) for characters.

Comment: This is a terrible answer. `char` can be compared against any integral type, and ASCII value is a billion miles away from `char`. In fact, it really doesn't make sense to suggest that `char` stores a character.